# Approximating original formula from a dataset

Tags: correlation, modeling, dataset

*Disclaimer: I don't have sufficient statistics' background or vocabulary for this question, but I did my best to do a preliminary search both within the forum and the broader interwebs*

Is there a way for one to determine a formula or its simplified approximation from a set of results?

My sole expectation of accuracy from such a "reverse-engineered" formula is the ability to reproduce the original set - or a set close enough to it - *not* the ability to further expand the set or introduce intermediate values.

Comment: I think if anyone is to answer this, they're going to need a lot more information about the data.  Are you trying to determine the distribution of a data set from the raw data?

Comment: Yes, we need for information. Can you provide a precise example ?

Comment: jonsca & steffen are right. We need to know something about your situation, your data, and your goals. You may find it helpful to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) & this blog post: [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/comment-page-1/) in reformulating your Q. If this Q cannot be made answerable, it will need to be closed. My 1st guess is that some form of regression modeling will help you recover the formula that generated the initial dataset, but it's hard to know which form w/o more info.

Comment: @gung: that's too bad. I was trying to purposefully avoid specifics rather than asking for a solution of an isolated case - something I thought to be the preferred format here on stackexchange (with the whole *teach a man to fish* thing). Andrew Dalke's answer was a perfect fit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Eureqa](http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa). It's "a software tool for detecting equations and hidden mathematical relationships in your data. Its goal is to identify the simplest mathematical formulas which could describe the underlying mechanisms that produced the data."

Comment: exactly what I was after